# How to type app.get('/events', (req, res) in express with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I would like to know what is the type annotation for `(req, res) =>` when using `app.get` in express.

```
app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
        // SSE Setup
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        });
        res.write('\n');

        sseEvents(req, res);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have `@types/express` (`npm i -D @types/express`) and then you can use

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
app.get('/events', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // your code
});
```